# X11 display over ssh with monitor connected to remote machine

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I have the following setup: Machine A (a.corp, 192.168.100.130, local machine) and Machine B (b.corp, remote machine) and a monitor is connected to *each* of these machines. When I ssh from a.corp to b.corp as

Machine A, local machine, i.e., a.corp set up:

`.ssh/config`

```
Host *
    ForwardX11 yes
    TCPKeepAlive no
    ServerAliveInterval 15
    ServerAliveCountMax 10
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa.work
```

`/etc/ssh_config` (it is a OS-x, Darwin 12.2.0)

```
Host *
  SendEnv LANG LC_*
  ForwardX11 yes
```

MachineB, remote machine, i.e., b.corp setup: (ubuntu kernel: 3.2.0)

`.ssh/config`

```
Host * 
    ForwardX11 yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa.work
```

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
Host * 
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    ForwardX11 yes
```

Case 1:

```
(DISPLAY on a.corp is not set)
$ echo $DISPLAY

$ ssh -X b.corp

(DISPLAY on b.corp is not set either)
$ echo $DISPLAY

$ xclock
Error: Can't open display:
```

Case 2: I tried setting the DISPLAY variable as

```
(DISPLAY on a.corp is not set)
$ echo $DISPLAY

$ ssh -X b.corp
$ export DISPLAY=`echo $SSH_CLIENT|cut -f1 -d\ `:0.0
$ echo $DISPLAY
192.168.100.130:0.0
$ xclock
```

xclock's display opens up but on the monitor connected to b.corp (remote machine) and not on the monitor connected to a.corp (local machine). Is there a way to force the display to appear on the monitor of the local machine (a.corp)?

Comment: 192.168.100.130 is the ip of which machine?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, `DISPLAY` must be set to `localhost:10.0` *on the remote machine*
You should also ensure that `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the *remote* machine has the line

`ForwardX11 Yes`

Under the section

`Host *`

or

`Host a.corp`

if you want to allow X11 forwarding to this host only.

Comment: If this worked for you, please consider updating the question so other people with the same problem can fix it.

Comment: You meant `DISPLAY` on the local machine or remote machine. If I set `DISPLAY` on remote machine to `localhost:10.0` I get `Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0`. I have updated the question with the config settings on both local and remote machine.

Comment: I meant on the remote machine (modified the answer).
This is usually set up by the -X switch, though; which makes me suspect that your configuration somehow blocks X11 forwarding. You mentioned looking in `.ssh/config` Which user's home were these in? Have you checked the system-wide files in `etc/ssh/ssh_config` ?

Comment: Joseph, I checked the system wide files as well. Nothing unusual there. I have updated the question with `/etc/ssh_config` information as well.

Comment: Well the system-wide files on machine B don't seem to indicate that it allows X11 forwarding. If you have the right privileges on machine B, try adding `ForwardX11 Yes` to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on it.

Comment: Tried that as well. Same results

Comment: I also found that with the above setting if I use machine B as a local machine and Machine A as a remote machine I get the same behavior, i.e., starting say `vi` on machine A after logging into it from machine B opens the gui on the screen attached to machine A.

Comment: I'm afraid what little experience I have fails me beyond this point. Have you tried what the other answerer suggested?

Comment: I tried the other answer as well. Same results.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  @Sumit did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting without using xauth:

client@home: ssh server -Y xeyes

If this works, then you'll have to look into setting up x11 security properly.

Comment: As I stated in the comments above this works same as -X option

Comment: Are you running su to become another user or something? If DISPLAY is not set in the "xterm" that lives in your local x session, then there is nowhere to forward to. The DISPLAY variable must be set before you try to x-forward something to it from a remote host. Can you start `xeyes` or similar at all from the terminal emulator where you shell into the remote server? If you can't even start things locally,  and you won't be able to do it unless DISPLAY is set, then it's no wonder forwarding isn't working. in case of su skip the - (new login shell). In case of sudo use the -E option.

Comment: No I am not using `su` or `sudo`. And yes xeyes opens up fine, just not on the right screen (I have updated the questions with exact behavior observed)

Comment: Nothing will open "just fine" when DISPLAY isn't set. Export the variable as :0.0 and then try to shell to the remote host with -Y like I suggested. To use an ip in the DISPLAY on the remote host, the local host must have run xhost +remotehost.com. Make sure that 192.168.100.130 means what you think it does on the remote host - that is your local computer. Finally make sure there are no firewall rules that restrict this type of traffic.